# Get selected list item in alert dialog with split string

Tags: android, listview, split, android-alertdialog

I have string array in strings.xml with the country phone numbers and the country name separated by a comma.
Now I want to show this list in a dialog and show the country phone number of the selected country in an edittext.

The list is shown, I can click an item and a number w/o the country name is shown in the edittext but unfortunately it's always the same value. It looks like I don't get the clicked item but iterate though the complete list and get something back.

Here's the code of the alert dialog:

```
private void selectCountry() {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_country);
final String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Countries);
builder.setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        String CountryZipCode = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            String[] g = names[i].split(",");
            CountryZipCode = g[0];
        }

        countrycode.setText("+" + CountryZipCode);
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
}
```

And here's a snippet of the array list from strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="Countries" >
    <item>93,Afghanistan</item>
    <item>355,Albania</item>
    <item>213,Algeria</item>
    <item>376,Andorra</item>
    <item>244,Angola</item>
</string-array>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it always the last one?

because if i am reading your code correctly thats what you are doing..

shouldn't you be saying:

```
builder.setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        String CountryZipCode = "";

        //for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            String[] g = names[item].split(",");
            CountryZipCode = g[0];
        //}

        countrycode.setText("+" + CountryZipCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right! It was always the last one! Thanks a lot for your fast reply!